# Add services to custom tags chain symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have code like in this [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html). But I want extend this. 
Now my code looks like this:

```
app.custom.chain:
    class: AppBundle\Type\CustomChain

app.type.main:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\MainType
    autowire: true
    tags:
        - { name: app.custom.type, alias: main }
```

In `MainType` I have `__construct` method with argument:

```
public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
{
    $this->om = $om;
}
```

And in `AppCustomTypePass`:

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    if (!$container->has('app.custom.chain')) {
        return;
    }

    $definition = $container->findDefinition('app.custom.chain');
    $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.custom.type');
    foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
        foreach ($tags as $attributes) {
            $definition->addMethodCall(
                'addCustomType',
                [
                    new Reference($id),
                    $attributes['alias'],
                ]
            );

        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting error:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function AppBundle\Form\Type\MainType::__construct(), 0 passed

How I can pass arguments in this class in my `AppCustomTypePass` class?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why don't you want to simply define `MainType` arguments in service definition?

Comment: @JakubMatczak because I need use custom service tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of one of my services. It's a custom form but you can at least see how arguments are supposed to be passed:

```
app.form.contact:
    class: AppBundle\Form\ContactType
    arguments: ["@translator.default"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

I dont know what the shortcut tag is supposed to be for the object manager, sorry but the one I passed in is the default translator for Symfony

Answer (score 0):

In the compiler pass you can set the arguments for tagged services with:

```
foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
        foreach ($tags as $attributes) {
            $tagDefinition = $container->findDefinition($id);
            $tagDefinition->addArgument(***);
            ...   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need pass arguments to `MainType`, not in `CustomChain`

Comment: fixed, if you still want to set the argument in the compiler pass